# How to add a new increment Field Value in my documents in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in Firestore with several documents in it and I wanted to know if it is possible to add one Field Value (e.x called index) and the value of this value is an increment from 0 to the length of the collection, having the first document "INDEX" : 0, second "INDEX": 1 and so on until it reaches the last document.

Comment: that looks a bit like an antipattern with nosql databases. Why exactly would you need to index it? I believe the why would be a better question here and people would help you come up with intelligent ideas.

Comment: @ThalesKenne I have a table in my front end where I show data that is stored in Firestore. I have made the table editable, so when the user changes a value inside a cell in the table, that new value is updated in Firestore. I just have a small problem, in the case where two or more values in the cells are the same, it changes all the cells with the new value. When I use limit(1), it changes the first that it finds. So I was thinking if I add an index value, I can use two conditions to find the exact value that should be changed: 1) the old value (which i currently use) 2)  index.

Comment: Alright, we're getting somewhere. So when two cells are the same, the entire document receives the values?

Comment: @ThalesKenne For example, if two cells under the column "Price" are equal (e.x 500), if I change the value of one cell to 550, both cells will change to 550. If I use .limit(1), it will change the first cell in order that has that value. I figured out that if I have an incremental index in every document, I can set a condition "where(index = changedRowIndex) since I am able to get the value of the index of the row that is changed. This would solve my problem.

Comment: What if each row in the table is a document? Then you'd only need to update the `price` for the document of that row. You could access the document straight from its ID. Of course I'm only suggesting, this decision would need consideration about pricing and database usage

Comment: @ThalesKenne Each row is a document in my case. All the documents have auto-generated IDs and there are like 100 rows or documents. I have 3 columns and my logic goes like this, I can detect the changing event for each column, if the event.column is Price, find where Price = event.oldValue and change Price to event.newValue. Same goes for other columns. In general it works, except the case when I have same values under a column. This is the problem.

Comment: But why do you need to query your documents again to find which document to update? You have that information already from the table. Just do a `doc('documentId').update({price: 550})` and it should work. Then either setup a listener to keep the table up to date or change it straight into your frontend object

Comment: That's how I do it, but it gets the document id wrong since they are two cells with the same value (500), and it updates the first one, even if the one that I edited was the second. It needs something to distinguish the cells, that's why I want an index so I can put another condition. The first document is the first row, the second doc is the second row, and so on. So if I have Price = 500 in row 1 and Price = 500 in row 3, if I have an index I can do it like this, where( price = event.oldValue (e.x 500) and index = changedRow.id (e.x 1)) , this way it will change only row 1.

Comment: Yes yes, I understand that. However, the document ID is unique for each document. If each row is a document and you update a single document, this should not be happening. You can actually try and hardcode a document ID in your code inside that where statement, if that's the case.